# How to send HTTPS requests to Apache server from Java application server using default snakeoil cert?

Tags: java, apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm running an apache2 web server with a HTTPS virtual host. I'd like to have a java application running on another server be able to send a HTTPS request to the apache server, but requests are failing because of `SSLHandShakeException`.

I'm not sure if I've done the right thing, but I've taken the `ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` file from the apache server and imported that into the java `cacerts` keystore on java application server. That fixed the initial `PKIX Path Building Failed...` error, but it's now replaced with another SSLHandShakeException which is `No name matching [mydomain.com] found`. I'm a bit lost.

The initial command I ran to import the cert into the keystore for the app was:

```
sudo keytool -import -file apache-cert.pem -alias mydomain.com -keystore /path/to/cacerts
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it wasn't working was because the snakeoil cert that Apache generated used the hostname of the server (obviously!) as the common name (CN) for the cert (it's an Amazon EC2 server so it has a hostname like ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.region). So that wasn't matching up with what my java application server was expecting (mydomain.com).

I generated a new cert/key pair for the Apache server e.g.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl 
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
```

...specifying mydomain.com as the CN in the options. I then edited my `sites-available` config to point to the new cert/key and then `sudo service apache2 restart`.

After that I copied the apache.crt file to the java server and ran

```
  sudo keytool -import -file apache.crt -alias mydomain.com -keystore /path/to/cacerts
```